# How to display image from MySQL after insert from Gallery?

Tags: php, android, mysql, bitmap, insert

I have a problem when I try to create a new project in android studio. I already connect to MySQL database. in the database there is a user table that has a field : username, password, and image (type data is blob). when I add (insert) data to the user table especially the image field manually from MySQL, then I do GetString on Android Studio and then I converted to bitmap. then I managed to display the image. But my problem is when I try to create a button pick from gallery and then I insert the bitmap to the user table in the picture field then I do GetString again to the picture I have just insert, but the result was the picture does not appear, please give the solution of the problems I have, thank you.
here is my code of php

```
<?php
$nm=$_POST['nama'];
$em=$_POST['email'];
$hm=$_POST['home'];
$ph=$_POST['phone'];
$gbr=$_POST['gambar'];
$pw=$_POST['pass'];



$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "needme");
$query = "INSERT INTO user(email,name,Password,AddressHome,Phone,gambar)      
values ('$em','$nm','$pw','$hm','$ph','$gbr')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("REPORT failed DATA.");

if ($result){
echo '1';
}
else{
echo '0';
}
?>
```

here is my code of java, btnReg is registration button

```
btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, URL_INSERT,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(Registration2.this, "Register Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Registration2.this, Login.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration2.this, "Register Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                        throws AuthFailureError {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    bm = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


                    //byte[] bmm = i.getByteArrayExtra("gambar");
                    //Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bit = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    boolean compress = bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bit);
                    byte[] byteImg = bit.toByteArray();
                    strImage = Base64.encodeToString(bit.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);


                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("nama", nama.getText().toString());
                    params.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                    params.put("home", home.getText().toString());
                    params.put("phone", phone.getText().toString());
                    params.put("gambar",strImage);
                    params.put("pass",pw.getText().toString());

                    return params;
                }

            };
            RequestQueue reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registration2.this);
            reqQueue.add(strRequest);

        }
    });
```

here is my code after pick from gallery or camera

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            iv.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);


            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
            int scale = 1;
            while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            bm1 = getResizedBitmap(bm2, 150, 150);
            bm = ImageConverter.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bm1, 100);
            //bm = GetBitmapClippedCircle(selectedImagePath);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

            cropCenter(bm);
            //int croppedBitmap;

        }
        //iv.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }
}
```